# getting Authorization Code and posting (User & Client) credentials to Authserver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I'm using .ne6 (c#)
I'm tring to get an authorization code from a redirect Uri (where i have to give a userName and Password/ User Credentials) then i need to post the authorizationCode to the Authorization Server (tokenUri) to retrieve the tokens and i've tried alot of different ways but non have worked.
Does any one know how to do it? i tried to do it with uri mapper and http context...
here's part of the code i just need the way to get the authCode from that redirectUrl
(User Credentials and Client Credentials i want to pass programmatically)

```
//Auth redirectUri
string oauthUri = SipgateRestApiHelper.GenerateOauthUri();

//
public class SipgateRestApiHelper
{
public static string ClientId { get; set; } = "xxx";
public static string ClientSecret { get; set; } = "xxx";
public static string RedirectUri { get; set; } = "http://localhost:xxxx/oauth";
public static string OauthUri { get; set; } = "https://login.sipgate.com/auth/realms/sipgate-       apps/protocol/openid-connect/auth";
public static string TokenUri { get; set; } = "https://login.sipgate.com/auth/realms/sipgate-  apps/protocol/openid-connect/token";
public static string OauthScope { get; set; } = "all";
public static int Port { get; set; } = 8080;
public static string SessionState { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
public static string Response_Type { get; set; } = "code";
}

//
public static string GenerateOauthUri()
{
StringBuilder sbUri = new StringBuilder(OauthUri);
sbUri.Append("?client_id=" + ClientId);
sbUri.Append("&redirect_uri=" + RedirectUri);
sbUri.Append("&scope=" + OauthScope);
sbUri.Append("&response_type=" + Response_Type);
sbUri.Append("&state=" + SessionState);

            return sbUri.ToString();
    
      }

///
public static async Task\<SipgateToken\> GetTokenByCode(string authorizationCode)
{

            SipgateToken token = null;
    
            var postData = new
            {
                client_id = ClientId,
                ClientSecret = ClientSecret,
                redirect_uri = RedirectUri,
                code = authorizationCode,
                response_type= "authorization_code"
            };
    
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient() { })
            {
                StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData), Encoding.Default, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    
                using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(TokenUri, content))
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    
                        token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SipgateToken>(responseString);
                    }
                }
                return token;
            }
        }

//
public async Task\<string\> GetTokens(string code)
{
var tokenStr = string.Empty;
string refreshToken = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
                {
                    var token = await SipgateApiHelper.GetTokenByCode(code);
                    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            return tokenStr;
        }

//

public class SipgateToken
{
public string Access_Token { get; set; } = string.Empty;
public string Token_Type { get; set; } = string.Empty;
public string Expires_In { get; set; } = string.Empty;
public string Refresh_Token { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

///
```

Comment: Hi BlackObsidian! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at IdentityModel it is a library that will allow you do any oauth2.0/oidc flow easily

Comment: Hi again, I've answered your question, you have some fundamental errors on your approach, I haven't realized when I posted my first comment. You're mixing client-credentials with code flow. Also, there are tools to help you build URLs and add query parameters so you don't have to use a string builder.

Comment: @PabloRecalde Thank You very much for your help. i know what you mean i just put the functions I'm using and credentials here all together but in the real app i've put them in appsettings and the functions in a controller but here just to make my question more clear. As for your answer about the worker in IdentityModel I'm still looking into it. and last but not least I'm not that experienced so,  there could be some foundemental mistakes i'm trying to fix :)

Answer (score 1):

There're libraries for .net 6.0 and earlier versions that allow you to implement an OAuth2.0 or OIDC client with a couple of lines:

I would recommend [IdentityModel](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/overview.html)

It's not just that this library simplifies your work, it is also that is tested, trusted by thousands, and also resolves some other problems like token lifecicle management

Based on IdentityModel documentation, you could do something like:

```
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    services.AddAccessTokenManagement(options =>
    {
        options.Client.Clients.Add("identityserver", new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
        {
            Address = "https://demo.identityserver.io/connect/token",
            ClientId = "m2m.short",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            Scope = "api" // optional
        });
    });
});
```

this registers an `AccessTokenManagementService` and a `ClientAccessTokenCache` that will be able to request and store the access token for you (the whole flow code + token)

then you can just do

```
services.AddClientAccessTokenClient("client", configureClient: client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("your api that is going to consume the access token URI");
});
```

to register an HTTP client (for your API) that will automatically request or use the cached access token on every call you make.

Last you just need to inject the `HTTPClientFactory` and request this named "client" which is already configured to obtain the access token and use it on every request.

```
public Worker(IHttpClientFactory factory)
{
    _client = factory.CreateClient("client");
}
```

Based on https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetcore/worker.html please consult this link for further information on this process.

**Note that in my example uses a CLIENT CREDENTIALS flow which is the one you should be using as**

1. You are a confidential client capable of keeping a secret (a program runnning in a server)
2. This a service 2 service comunication with no user involved AFAICS

This flow does not involve redirect-uris, and is done on a single request to `/token` endpoint, not `/auth` but again those are low level details about the protocol that `IdentityModel` will take care of if you choose to use it.